# SMTPException One of the streams has already been used and can't be reset to the origin

Tags: c#, email, smtp

When I'm trying to send an email with attachment with more than one recipients through my C# code an System.Net.Mail.SmtpException is thrown saying "Failure sending mail."
The inner exception is "One of the streams has already been used and can't be reset to the origin."

I understand this kind of error maybe happening because of my attachment.
I have created my attachment in a different class as -

```
Attatchment file;
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
file = Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(fileContents, fileName);
```

I'm sending it in this format to my class that sends the email. The following happens in that class -

```
try
{    
     email.Subject = subject;
     email.Body = body;
     if (file != null)
     {
         email.Attachments.Add(file);
     }
    _smtpClient.Send(email);
}   
catch
{
     mailSent = false;
}
```

The mail is always sent to the first recipient but fails for all the rest.
Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: I am guessing you may need to dispose of 'file' before attempting to use it again.

Comment: @ChrisBint Would you be able to tell me why? Because this error doesn't consistently happen either. This is the first time it has cropped up. I've been using it for a while. I'll try that now though, thank you.

Comment: @ChrisBint I'd be more inclined to guess that `file` internally has a stream object which cannot be reset back to start.

Comment: Do you really need to send 1 mail per recipient or can you send 1 mail to all recipients? Use the `Bcc` property to hide all the recipients from each other.

Comment: @DavidG I think bcc would work, but I'm working on legacy code and trying to not add to the bloat of that class. The SMTP portion has been there a while.  But I could do that, should nothing else work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Internally to the `Attachment` class it appears to use a `Stream` to contain the data. Some types of stream don't allow you to reset the position back to the start and will throw an `InvalidOperationException` with the message you see above.

Your solutions are:

1. Send a single mail but put all recipients in the [`Bcc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc(v=vs.110).aspx) field.
2. Create the attachment for each mail you send - do not reuse the same object each time.
3. This may not work, but you could try using the constructor for `Attachment` that takes a stream as a parameter instead of string. Put all your string data into a `MemoryStream` which does allow repositioning. For example:

   ```
   public Stream StringToStream(string s)
   {
       MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
       StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
       writer.Write(s);
       writer.Flush();
       stream.Position = 0;
       return stream;
   }
   ```

   Then this:

   ```
   var stream = StringToStream(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
   Attatchment file = new Attachment(stream, fileName);
   ```

---

Note: You are initialising the attachment object incorrectly. In the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9089e309(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes two `string` parameters, the second parameter is the media type, not the filename.

Comment: Oh. Is there some way we could set the name of the file in the attachment? Most of the online helps seems to suggest setting the name property which is actually the MIME content type.

Comment: Yes, the name property is what you should use.

Answer (score 4):

In our case it was the `LinkedResource` instance (file-attachment, embedded into an email as an inline image) that was RE-USED for multiple messages. And messages were `.Dispose`'d after sending - which closed all the underlying streams.

I guess it essentially boils down to @DavidG's answer, just adding my two cents - remember to check embedded resources not just plain attachments.

Comment: LinkedResource was the culprit for me, too.  In order to loop through the sending of multiple e-mails, I needed to recreate each LinkedResource on each iteration.